# Windows 7 keep popping up message to format drive

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7 keep popping up this message to format the MMC drive - I have no idea which drive that is.

[image]

The above is the image I took and keeps popping up a lot more now. So annoying! It happens since the last two weeks but that time, I just simply clicked cancel and it went away till next time I turned on my laptop. However today, it keep popping up non-stop!

Any advice what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a memory card in your computer. Format it or disable the memory card reader, and the message will go away.

Comment: No i don't have any memory card in my laptop at all.Although, i'm using USB wireless mouse and that's all. The message pops up at random time though, it's like out of no where, it pops up for like 10 mins or sth then stop for a while then starts again.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the Elevated Command Prompt and checking it:

1. Click Start and type `cmd`, then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`
2. Click `Continue` or `Yes` if prompted by UAC
3. Type `chkdsk i: /f /r` and press `Enter`

Wait for it to finish, and see if the drive is then usable. Look at the output as well, and make sure it shows `0KB in Bad Sectors` when done